# How to truncate variable in template Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

i need your help to know how to truncate my variable in my template.

this is my code :

```
<p class="card-text">{{$new['content']}}</p>
```

i would truncate this variable $new['content'] at 150 characters with '...' at end.

Can you help me please ?

I work on Laravel 5.6

Thanks all ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  @if(strlen($new['content'])>150)                                     
       {{substr(strip_tags($new['content']),0,150)}}...
  @else
      {{$new['content']}}
  @endif
```

Comment: Wow ! this condition is amazing too ! thanks Mahesh xD

Answer (score 1):

You may use laravel helper (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-str-limit) and add `...` after it.

```
str_limit($new['content'], 150)
```

*Much better way:* it won't display `...` if ur content is less than 150 character:

```
str_limit($new['content'], 150, '...');
```

Comment: Larvel 8 -  `\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit()`